# knockout option routing navigation

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, knockout.js

I am using  Drop down list for navigation

```
<select data-bind="options:router.navigationModel ,optionsText: function (item) {return item.title;}, optionsValue:function (item) { return item.hash;} "></select>
```

I am expecting on option select  it has to route to corrosponding hash page but not routing.

How can I route.

```
<select>
    <option value="#home">Home</option>
    <option value="#contactus">Contact us</option>
    <option value="#about">About</option>
</select>
```

Comment: show what you have tried. try creating a jsfiddle with your work. noone will do your work for you unless you show some effort

Comment: Routing functionality is provided by Sammy.js NOT knockout.js